MetagenomeSeq won't install, error says it is not available for Bioconductor version
I am trying to update R and all packages after not working with it for a few years.  I am on a MAC running Sonoma 14.6.1. I need to install MetagenomeSeq for some analysis work and am running into a problem installing it.
I have updated R to version 4.4.1 and R studio to Version 2024.09.0+375
I have installed BioConductor version 3.20 using the command
install.packages("BiocManager")
I have verified that BiocManager is turned on in the packages tab of R Studio
I can install other packages using the command
BiocManager::install("name_of_package",force=TRUE)
But when I try the command
BiocManager::install("metagenomeSeq",force=TRUE)
I get the following error

Warning message:
package ‘metagenomeSeq’ is not available for Bioconductor version '3.20'

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
I tried installing it directly in R instead of R studio and I get the same error.
The MetagenomeSeq page at https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/metagenomeSeq.html
Indicates that it should run with Bioconductor 3.20
I also tried the code listed on the bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/metagenomeSeq.html page
Any suggestions appreciated

What about installing it directly from github, like: install_github("Bioconductor-mirror/metagenomeSeq") from {remotes} package?

It looks like that package is erroring out while testing on the Bioconductor build servers. As another commenter suggested, you can try installing the package directly from github, though I would contact the maintainers and see if they're still active. Alternatively, you can download a prior version of R and the correlated Bioconductor version and that should still work.
